# Jasper Report - Detail won't print on first page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report set up with a Title band and a Detail band containing a table. There is no spacing between these two bands. When I view/print the report, the Detail band begins printing at the top of page 2, and page 1 is left with a large blank space between the header and the footer.

How can I get the Detail band to print directly beneath the title on page 1?

Edit: Code below.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Summary" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="24a40acb-a702-48a6-b655-04f85fdba2a9">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    ...
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                ...
            </staticText>
            ...
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="753" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="3835c484-c5a2-4615-8018-b95d8d0b7f43" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="753" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    ...
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                ...
            </staticText>
            ...
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: please insert the specifications of your detail band (the `<detail ...>` part) and your title band

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the detail band is so large that the report starts it on the second page to display as much of it as possible.

`printWhenDetailOverflows` should be the relevant parameter.

If your report is small enough (or the result is what you desired) you can set `ignorePagination` on the top element to `true` and get everything in one page.

Also, you have a `pageHeight` of `842`, minus `40` margin makes `802` per page.
Your `detail` band is `753`, the `title` is `79`, so they don't fit together on one page.

Comment: I've added this property to the report element but it did not seem to cause any change.

Comment: @Bort I got it. Have a look at my edited answer. That worked after I imported your example. The problem is that your bands are to large for the page.