# JasperReport Table column overflow - not showing on first page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report with Table in detail band. I have a few columns with  in Table that have more than 1500 characters with new line or paragraph.

My Jrxml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.3.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="print_ror" pageWidth="1008" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="968" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6d782990-b663-4852-bd17-a0f370c5d069">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="connpg"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="rordataset" uuid="9a743b16-3c04-4a9a-87ec-ccfefce3b8a5">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="connpg"/>
        <parameter name="vcc1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="acno1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="part1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[SELECT khata_number,   land_revenue_payable,   device_serialno,name,father,address,khasra_no,
    area,   yr_co_ten,  order_desc , remark_desc 
FROM up_khata_detail ukd
]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="khata_number" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="khata_number"/>
        </field>
        <field name="land_revenue_payable" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="land_revenue_payable"/>
        </field>
        <field name="device_serialno" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="device_serialno"/>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="name"/>
        </field>
        <field name="father" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="father"/>
        </field>
        <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="address"/>
        </field>
        <field name="khasra_no" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="khasra_no"/>
        </field>
        <field name="area" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="area"/>
        </field>
        <field name="yr_co_ten" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="yr_co_ten"/>
        </field>
        <field name="order_desc" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="order_desc"/>
        </field>
        <field name="remark_desc" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="remark_desc"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="vcc" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["740925"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="acno" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["00880"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="part" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ktype" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["G"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="villname" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["ग्राम "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="parg" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["परगना "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="teh" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["तहसील "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="dist" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["जिला "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="fy" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["वर्ष "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ltype" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["श्रेणी "]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ukd.khata_number,
    ukd.land_revenue_payable,
    ukd.device_serialno,
    uod.name,
    uod.father,
    uod.address,
    ugd.khasra_no,
    ugd.area,
    ugd.yr_co_ten,
    uo.order_desc,
    urd.remark_desc
FROM up_khata_detail ukd
WHERE 
     ukd.village_code_census = $P{vcc} 
     AND ukd.khata_number =   $P{acno} 
     AND ukd.part =    $P{part} 
 limit 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="khata_number" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="khata_number"/>
    </field>
    <field name="land_revenue_payable" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="land_revenue_payable"/>
    </field>
    <field name="device_serialno" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="device_serialno"/>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="name"/>
    </field>
    <field name="father" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="father"/>
    </field>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="address"/>
    </field>
    <field name="khasra_no" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="khasra_no"/>
    </field>
    <field name="area" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="area"/>
    </field>
    <field name="yr_co_ten" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="yr_co_ten"/>
    </field>
    <field name="order_desc" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="order_desc"/>
    </field>
    <field name="remark_desc" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="remark_desc"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="244" y="20" width="266" height="49" uuid="51cd430d-fee5-4ced-8418-9c981b7cc8f0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="25"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Details]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="252" height="18" uuid="ed64e7b8-034b-4411-9efa-eba6aa33b6bc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ग्राम का नाम / परगना : " + $P{villname} + " (" +$P{parg} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="402" y="0" width="160" height="18" uuid="0f9aa4d6-8816-4667-a968-881f7e7ed0b9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["तहसील : " +$P{teh}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="567" y="0" width="160" height="18" uuid="d4b96345-ad1e-47cc-a2b4-18a05469e243"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["जनपद : " +$P{dist}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="737" y="0" width="130" height="18" uuid="7a2b9306-d458-41ef-bd0d-6ef6f39299f1"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["फसली वर्ष  :" +$P{fy}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="880" y="0" width="80" height="18" uuid="c41fcb6c-b390-4866-a01d-ab691e688119"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["भाग : " +$P{part}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="6" y="22" width="390" height="18" uuid="5171a2ce-4218-4869-8331-c990c9a6cb18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["श्रेणी : " +$P{ltype}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="120" splitType="Immediate">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="949" height="120" uuid="09e2de12-7560-402a-8534-39ee28af6857">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="rordataset" uuid="1c70e75a-2118-4b10-8733-1bbcd64c1c35">
                        <datasetParameter name="acno1">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{acno}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="part1">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{part}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="vcc1">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{vcc}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="2e9638ee-aff4-4901-b3de-94e2fbb27623">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="60" uuid="d218b428-d7f2-4ef3-92a7-5542c284219c"/>
                                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[खाता खतौनी क्रम संख्या
--1--]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="7be936dd-a4fe-41b1-bd9e-aa38d788bac8"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{khata_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="160" uuid="5bc0d996-5bcc-4b1c-8981-1fa1e312bc46">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="160" height="60" uuid="22ef4ac8-efc0-4875-ba47-fafbcf0ba5f9"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[खातेदार का नाम / पिता पति संरक्षक का नाम / निवास स्थान
 -------2---------   ]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" uuid="c6569715-8f72-4ac8-ae09-4ef9f4f4b875"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="c7c85bce-f830-4b39-8108-c824f0217f37">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="60" uuid="e8a0b25b-61b3-4cf9-a4ef-dae08e4d53a0"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[भौमिक अधिकार प्रारम्भ होने का वर्ष 
-----3-----]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="721de5ce-18be-4e88-94ad-98ae57e8909f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{yr_co_ten}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="16a61075-bd7e-4e9d-977e-3110f651ed5d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="60" uuid="43107490-6fea-4f2c-9c93-095e53bde14e"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[खाते के प्रत्येक गाटे की खसरा संख्या 
------------4----------]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="8f425cbb-eb6e-4bff-a5c6-37ec942deb99"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{khasra_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="75" uuid="0a933dc7-f97a-4b7f-bcf9-b25bfd99acf3">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="60" uuid="5fd9529f-d80c-4cc5-9375-aa7b8d6fde07"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[प्रत्येक गाटे का क्षेत्रफल (हे.) 
-------5--------]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="30" uuid="317e4a23-2a0a-4bc0-8ad0-52cdc061f8bc"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{area}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="85" uuid="3c03b396-d7e5-4016-bde5-6e3c4eaaaf38">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="85" height="60" uuid="0d41b63e-cbc5-4502-bed3-3cbf1db4f0a1"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[खातेदार द्वारा देय मालगुजारी या लगान 
------6-------]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="30" uuid="ae8f8974-cf56-4648-8a79-d6d3ab3727b4"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{land_revenue_payable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="240" uuid="3605e60f-e456-4ba5-b4af-c340d135bf05">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column7"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="240" height="60" uuid="4c221671-a5b6-4da4-b654-7873ffd9a52a"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[परिवर्तन सम्बन्धी आज्ञा या उसका सारांश उनकी संख्या तथा दिनाँक सहित और आज्ञा देने वाले आधिकारी का पद 
-------------------------------7-12-------------------]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="30" uuid="4b39b572-4db1-4e32-ac99-803feede037b"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{order_desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="e9b6c705-d081-4f00-9843-60594e841b2d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column8"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="60" uuid="462b8792-a6c7-47b7-b0b3-1c252db98162"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[                      टिप्पणी        
----------13-----------------]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cf5966d8-e69e-4279-92f6-8ad64cbbacde"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{remark_desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

First page have BLANK Table Data, only table header is visible. Data is showing from Second page. I have gone through several SO post  [The first page is blank! Why?](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/516849/first-page-blank-why), and [Jasper Report - Detail won't print on first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656963/jasper-report-detail-wont-print-on-first-page) .

How to show data from First page ?

Answer (score 4):

Your table generates very high detail rows due to the fact that some of your textFields have `Stretch With Overflow` set to `true`.

The fact that no table detail gets shown on the first page is a known issue(that is going to get fixed in an upcoming JasperReports release) caused by the way the table component internally works. It generates bands with `splitType="Prevent"` for its details, thus preventing its rows to stretch across pages.

A quick, but destructive fix is to set `Stretch With Overflow` to `false` and lose data where the field values are extremely large.

But the recommended workaround, for now, is to move the table logic into a subReport where you are in control of your band `splitType` settings.

Comment: 2020, version 16.4.0 still nothing fixed. Very sad

Answer (score 0):

Since JasperReports version 6.20.1 it is possible to specify a splitType attribute for the table bands. Prior to that, the splitType of table component bands was hardcoded to Prevent, hence the problem.